# Adding multiple pictureboxes to a form programmatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, collections, visual-studio-2013, picturebox

So I have written a short section of code to add 6 pictureboxes to a form in random locations. It adds each picturebox to a collection, then loops through the collection and adds them to the form control. The bizarre issue is that the code only works when I step through it line by line in debug mode. If I just compile and run the code then only 1 picturebox is added to the form, but if I step through the code line by line then all 6 pictureboxes are successfully added to the form in random locations. Can anyone tell me why the hell this happening? It's driving me pretty nuts. Code below:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        Dim pic As New PictureBox
        Dim rnd As New Random
        pic.Location = New Point(rnd.Next(200, 300), rnd.Next(200, 300))
        pic.Size = New Size(5, 5)
        pic.BackColor = Color.White
        pic.Visible = True
        pic.BringToFront()
        _picCollection.Add(pic)
    Next

    For Each item As PictureBox In _picCollection
        Controls.Add(item)
    Next

    ShowDialog()
```

Open to suggestions of how to do this better / in a way that actually works properly.

Comment: Try declaring `rnd` only once, outside the loop.  Chances are it's getting declared with the same seed so it's returning the same values each time.

Comment: Rnd is working correctly, each picturebox is being created with different random coordinates. I made sure to check this. The code works fine when I step through it in debug mode.

Comment: The difference could be because the automatic seed is based, I believe, on time of day.  When you run it outside of VS it runs faster which could mean that debug will show you're getting different numbers but the published version is getting the same numbers.  Either way it usually makes more sense to declare a Random object outside of the loop and is a very simple and easy thing to test.

Comment: That's interesting, I wouldn't have guessed it would've been based on time. Anyway your suggestion worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to declare RND object outside of loop. Thanks tinstaafl!