# Adding multiple pictureboxes to a form programmatically in vb.net ?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

i have to add pictueboxes in to a panel as per my requirement .

"[Adding multiple pictureboxes to a form programmatically in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162089/adding-multiple-pictureboxes-to-a-form-programmatically-in-vb-net) "  In this question PictureBox are drawn in random but i want it in a synchronous way 
    enter code here

```
Dim i As String = ListBox1.Items.Count
For j As Integer = 0 To i
Dim PicBox As New PictureBox
PicBox.Width = 40
PicBox.Top = 25
PicBox.Left = j + 15
PicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
PicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(PicBox)
Next
```

i want to use counter which automatically check the value of i ?

Any idea or suggestion ?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like that is what you're doing. What are you having an issue with?

Comment: how can i get more space between 2 picturebox  in this way. it looks like one

Comment: From The above link , instead of ramdom . can it be in synchronised mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Private Sub PicBoxTestButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PicBoxTestButton.Click
    Try
        Dim numberOfPics As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
        Dim lastLeft As Integer = 15
        Const spacer As Integer = 5
        For parser As Integer = 0 To numberOfPics
            Dim PicBox As New PictureBox
            PicBox.Width = 40
            PicBox.Top = 25
            PicBox.Left = lastLeft
            lastLeft = PicBox.Width + PicBox.Left + spacer
            PicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            Me.Panel2.Controls.Add(PicBox)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: is there any possible to initalise it through a array

Comment: What would be in the array?