# How to add new PictureBox to form and Array

Tags: vb.net

G'day everyone, I'm currently working on a major project for an assessment and have reached an error. I've barely had any experience with arrays. Basically there's a whole heap of random pictures-boxes in an array that spawn at random location on left side of screen at random times and move across to the right. You control a GIF image helicopter which moves up, down, forward (left), and backwards (right). When space is pressed it creates a  new picture box that contains an animated image of a missile firing and rotating which moves across to the left of the screen. When it reaches the end it deletes itself, but if it hits an object it plays an explosion via timer and image list inside picture box then deletes itself and hides hit image.

I've attached all code relating to the missile array.

' General Declarations

```
Public Class frmPlay
Public Vertical As Integer
Public Horizontal As Integer
Dim WhichKey As String
Dim NumofObjs As Integer
Public F As Integer
Dim Missile() As PictureBox
Public ABC As Integer
```

' To Fire

```
Private Sub frmPlay_KeyDown
Select Case e.KeyValue
    Case Keys.Space
            If GameMode = "Protector" Then
                Dim Missile As PictureBox = New PictureBox
                Missile.Height = "14"
                Missile.Width = "72"
                Missile.ImageLocation = "graphics-helicopters-381058.gif"
                Missile.Enabled = True
                Missile.Show()
                Missile.Tag = "Missile"
                Me.Controls.Add(Missile)
                CentreOn(picChar, Missile)
                ABC += 1
                ReDim Missile(ABC)
            End If
```

' Collision Event on Object Move event

```
Dim ABC As Integer
    For Each obj In Me.Controls
        If GameMode = "Protector" Then
            If TypeOf obj Is PictureBox AndAlso obj.Tag.Contains("Obj") Then
                obj.Left += 20
                For ABC = 0 To 2 Step 1
                    If Collision(obj, Missile(ABC)) Then
                        If obj.Tag.Contains(lblCriteria.Text) Then
                            Missile(ABC).Visible = False
                            Missile(ABC).Enabled = False
                            obj.Visible = False
                            If picExplosion1.Visible = True And picExplosion2.Visible = False And picExplosion3.Visible = False Then
                                picExplosion2.Visible = True
                                tmrExplosion2.Start()
                                CentreOn(obj, picExplosion2)
                            ElseIf picExplosion1.Visible = True And picExplosion2.Visible = True And picExplosion3.Visible = False Then
                                picExplosion3.Visible = True
                                tmrExplosion3.Start()
                                CentreOn(obj, picExplosion3)
                            ElseIf picExplosion1.Visible = False Then
                                picExplosion1.Visible = True
                                tmrExplosion1.Start()
                                CentreOn(obj, picExplosion1)
                            Else
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next ABC
            End If
        End If
```

' Move Missile

```
Private Sub tmrMissiles_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrMissiles.Tick
    For CBA = 0 To 2 Step 1
        Missile(CBA).Left -= 10
        If Missile(CBA).Left <= -Missile(CBA).Width Then
            Me.Controls.Remove(Missile(CBA))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

' Declare Array in formLoad event

```
Private Sub frmPlay_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ABC As Integer = 0
    For Each obj In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf obj Is PictureBox AndAlso obj.Tag = "Missile" Then
            Missile(ABC) = obj
            obj.Hide()
            obj.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

There's a whole heap of other code related to graphics and the enemy move and character move etc but it all works perfectly. And I did have it working fine for the Missile fire event, however you could only fire three at a time, and had to wait for one to either hit an enemy or reach the end of the screen.

So how do I make it so that I can create an array for the missiles, that starts empty, then when space is pressed it creates a new picBox, adds to controls and arrays and moves using the missile array timer tick event? Please keep the code relatively the same style as what I have so I don't have to learn a whole heap of new stuff, thanks.

Thanks everyone, Burge-o

Comment: If you want to do this an `OOP` way then you use `GDI+` and build a missile class and any other things you draw. Then you just draw them in the paint event. This is a better way than a control heavy create and destroy model.

Comment: @OneFineDay. Yeah it probably would be. But I don't really understand the idea of making a new class for such a task. Class use confuses me, I understand functions and sub but as I've only taught myself everything with the help of a dodgy old text book that only covers the basics I haven't made a new class before.

Comment: you can check this  .it is for multiple picturebox 
  
[check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244018/adding-multiple-pictureboxes-to-a-form-programmatically-in-vb-net